# JavaFX set automatical End-LocalDateTime after choosing Start-LocalDateTime

Tags: java, javafx, time, localdate

I want to create a small GUI for some Data in addiction to date values. So I'm working with `LocalDateTimeTextField` in JavaFX. So I will get the chosen Time with the following code:

```
LocalDateTimeTextField tend;
LocalDateTimeTextField tbegin;

String en = tend.getLocalDateTime().withSecond(0).toString();
String ende = en.replaceAll("T", " ");
String endezeit = ende.substring(11, 16);
String be = tbegin.getLocalDateTime().withSecond(0).toString();
String begin = be.replaceAll("T", " ");
String beginzeit = begin.substring(11, 16);
String datum = begin.substring(0, 10);
```

As output I will get:

```
System.out.println("Beginn:    "+datum + " " + beginzeit);
System.out.println("Ende:      "+datum + " " + endezeit);
```

> Beginn:    2017-03-08 00:00 
>   Ende:      2017-03-08 23:59

[image: Choosen Time]

So for getting the Time for the Begining and the End I have to choose both Dates manually.

Is there a solution, to generate automatically a given Endtime, for example 1 Hour after the choosen starting Time? So that I have less "work" to edit the Times and in best case only have to choose one date.

---

Thank you for your suggestions! They´re working fine:)

```
    LocalDateTime timebegin = tbegin.getLocalDateTime().withSecond(0);
    LocalDateTime timeend = timebegin.plusHours(23).plusMinutes(59).plusSeconds(59);
    LocalDate datum = timebegin.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime start = timebegin.toLocalTime().plusSeconds(0);
    LocalTime ende = timeend.toLocalTime();
    tend.setLocalDateTime(timeend);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But now I knew, that my question was not right couched, because I still want to change the Enddate `tend` in the application. But there is no chance, because it's fixed to 23:59:59h after the `tbegin`. But my idea was to set the `tbegin` with a date and automatically set the `tend` to 23:59:59h after, but with also changing maybe to 10:00:00h after. But maybe I have to create a Button, which do these interim step. So to understand, what I want, here some pictures:

[image: Before/After clicking the Button]

So it should give me the field with the Enddate before I'm clicking the Button. And it should be possible, to edit the enddate to some other date/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but can't you simply call `tend.setLocalDateTime(...)` whenever `tbegin.localDateTimeProperty()` changes?

I.e.

```
tbegin.localDateTimeProperty().addListener((obs, oldTime, newTime) -> 
    tend.setLocalDateTime(newTime.plusHours(1)));
```

---

As an aside, you should not rely on string representations in order to extract data from an object. If the implementation of the `toString()` method changes, your code will break. You should also use the formatting API to convert dates and times to strings, instead of relying on `toString`. You should do, for example:

```
LocalDateTime end = tend.getLocalDateTime();

// if you need these:
LocalDate endDate = end.toLocalDate();
LocalTime endTime = end.toLocalTime();

// to display:
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm");
String stringEnd = formatter.format(end);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help:) I never really realised the fact with the formatter:) Thanks a lot! Now i have updated my question, with a new/old problem :D

Answer (score 1):

To get a `LocalDateTime` 1 hour after another, use the `plusHours` method:

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
// new date 1 hour after dt
LocalDateTime newDt = dt.plusHours(1);
```

And to control the output format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(formatter.format(dt));
```

This code will output (reminding that it's the current date/time in my timezone):

> 25.06.2017 17:42:50

For the other cases, you don't need to use `replace` and `substring`. Just use the formatters as well:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;

System.out.println(fmt1.format(dt));
System.out.println(fmt2.format(dt));
```

The output will be:

> 17:42
>   2017-06-25

Check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details about the output patterns.

---

When you call `timebegin.plusHours(23).plusMinutes(59).plusSeconds(59)`, you're adding a period to the date. If `timebegin` is at 10:00, the result will be the next day at `09:59:59`.

If you want to set the time to be **exactly** at `23:59:59`, you should do:

```
LocalDateTime timeend = timebegin.with(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
```

This will set `timeend` at `23:59:59`, no matter what's the time in `timebegin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped:) But now i have the problem, that it is not possible, to edit the enddate, because it is set fixed to 23:59:59h after the beginning date. Therefor i have updated my question :D maybe you have further ideas :D thank you:)

Comment: @Franky I'm not sure I understood what you want, but anyway I've updated the answer.